# bin/magento setup:di:compile throws Source class “-------” for “-------” generation does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.1

I downloaded a extension from github to my localhost and edited the Namespace/Module in the project. Everything seems alright but when i run the command `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile` i get the error

> > [RuntimeException]
> >     Source class "\Namespace\Module\Model\LogInterface" for "Namespace\Module\Model\LogRepository" generation does not exist.

Looking for other solutions, i added this in my etc/di.xml but it doest work

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Model\Entity\RepositoryFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="entities" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\LogInterface" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Api\LogRepositoryInterface</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

How else can i solve this ?

PS: i deleted the generation folder and run the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and after i run the `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile` but get same error

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```